# Software Updater runs and displays "up to date", then again later in a few minutes, then again later in a few minutes, then again later , etc

Tags: update-manager

I usually manually run Software Updater when I start the system - (20.04.5)

Then a few minutes later it runs again, and displays "up to date", then a a few minutes later it runs again, and displays "up to date", a few minutes later it runs again, and displays "up to date", a few minutes later it runs again, and displays "up to date", etc...

- I can't always be sure I will remember to run it, but highly probably I will
- The following is most desirable events:
  -I run Updater upon start
  -I don't see Updater again, unless an update has become available during this run time, when it will appear displaying the update for action.

  - If I forget to run updater, it will run ONCE soon after startup, and only again if a new update appears during that run time.
    Second choice - Updater runs only when I manually start it.

Comment: this occurs even when the system is set to automatically check for updates too...